# Jquery form problem. Adding removing options from selectbox

Tags: jquery, forms, select, append

I have a form with a lot of options.

In the form, I can make the data private or public so;

1. Make the data private : yes, no (radio buttons)
2. If clicked yes, displaying a hidden div with 2 more form options;
   a. member name search (text input)
   b. selected members (multi selectbox).

If I click make the data private "yes", and search for a username, it is displaying found results like a suggestion box. When I click on a username (in one of the found results displaying in suggestion box), I can add it successfully to my multi selectbox (selected members)

If I decide to make it public and click make the data private "no" after adding some members to my multi selectbox (selected members), I'm deleting all options, and adding 1 option back in there (Public View).

The problem starts after here. Before submitting the form, if I click make the data private "yes" again, (1; clicked yes, selected some members, 2; clicked no and removed all options from selectbox, 3; clicked yes again), search for some members and click on them, it is adding 2 times in my multi selectbox (selected members).

Interestingly, if I do it 2 times (add some members, click no for privacy and delete options), next time when I want to add some members it is adding 2 times. If I do it 5 times, it is adding 5 times.

Here is my Jquery;

```js
// Private Options
$('input[name=make_private]').bind('click', function() {
    // Make It Private
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeIn(1000);
        // Get clicked member
        $('a.member').live('click', function() {
            var username = $(this).text();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            // Add it to the Allowed Members Multi Selectbox
            $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", id).text(username).attr("selected", "selected"));
            // Don't load the page
            return false;
        });
    }
    // Make It Public
    else {
        // Hide everything about Product Privacy
        $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeOut(1000);
        // Remove All Options
        $("#allowedMembers option").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        // Add Public Option
        $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 0).text("Public View"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way, moving $('a.member').live('click') outside of $('input[name=make_private]').bind('click') did the trick. Thank you Ron for guiding me.

```
// Private Options
$('input[name=make_private]').bind('click', function () {
    // Make It Private
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    // Make It Public
    else {
        // Hide everything about Product Privacy
        $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeOut(1000);
        // Remove All Options
        $("#allowedMembers option").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });         
        // Add Public Option
        $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 0).text("Public View"));
    }
});
// Get clicked member
    $('a.member').live('click', function () {
        var username = $(this).text();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        // Add it to the Allowed Members Multi Selectbox
        $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", id).text(username).attr("selected","selected"));
        // Don't load the page
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are binding events multiple time you should `.unbind()` first. Otherwise you will have multiple (and maybe same) events bound to the same action

Try

```
('input[name=make_private]').unbind().bind('click', function () {
// Make It Private
if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeIn(1000);
    // Get clicked member
    $('a.member').unbind().live('click', function () {
        var username = $(this).text();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        // Add it to the Allowed Members Multi Selectbox
        $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", id).text(username).attr("selected","selected"));
        // Don't load the page
        return false;
    });
}
// Make It Public
else {
    // Hide everything about Product Privacy
    $('.frm_make_private_1').fadeOut(1000);
    // Remove All Options
    $("#allowedMembers option").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });         
    // Add Public Option
    $('#allowedMembers').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 0).text("Public View"));
}
});
```

Comment: Hello Ron, firstly thank you for your answer. Where should I exactly use it and how should I use it? I am not an expert, I would be glad if you could help.

Comment: Hello Ron, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately adding .unbind() infront of bind('click') and live('click') didn't do the trick :(

Comment: Found the way, moving $('a.member').live('click') outside of $('input[name=make_private]').bind('click') did the trick. Thanks for helping. I would like to accept your reply as solution (assisted one at least) but I don't know if it is good way to go. I'm new here, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No worries. Only accept solutions that solve the problem. So people who find this question in the future don't get confused. Vote up anything that is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am too low on reputation to be able to vote for now. Will do it once I can. Once again, thank you.